# How to get rectangle circumference point from angle

Tags: javascript, math

How to obtain the point of circumference of a rectangle with its size and angle?

```
function getRectangleCircumferencePoint(rectangle ,angle) {
    // rectangle.width
    // rectangle.height
    // angle

    return ???
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this help](http://www2.isu.edu/success/math/handouts/area_perimeter_circumference.pdf) if you have a problem with your code post here. but you need to do your own code first

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the frame of reference is centered at the rectangle center. One could proceed by first determining which side of the rectangle is "affected" by a particular value of the angle and then calculate the missing second coordinate:

```
W = 8;
H = 4;

function point(W, H, angle){

    var phi = Math.abs(Math.atan2(H, W));

    //transform angle into interval [0, 2*PI)
    var alpha = angle - Math.PI*2*Math.floor(angle / (Math.PI*2));
    var x, y;

    if(alpha <= phi || alpha >= 2*Math.PI-phi){ //right border
        x = +W/2;
    }else if(alpha >= Math.PI - phi && alpha <= Math.PI + phi){ //left border
        x = -W/2;
    }else if(alpha > phi && alpha < Math.PI - phi){ //top border
        y = +H/2;
    }else{ //bottom border
        y = -H/2;
    }

    if(x === undefined){
        //alpha might be here pi/2 so it's probably better to expand tan(alpha) rather
        //than divide by "+inf"
        x = y * Math.cos(alpha) / Math.sin(alpha);
    }else if(y === undefined){
        y = x * Math.tan(alpha);
    }

    return [x, y];
}

N = 4;
for(var i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    var alpha = i*2*Math.PI/N;
    var pnt = point(W, H, alpha);
    console.log(pnt[0].toFixed(8), pnt[1].toFixed(8));
}
```

this then prints:

```
4.00000000 0.00000000
0.00000000 2.00000000
-4.00000000 0.00000000
-0.00000000 -2.00000000
```